# How to configure django to run on apache

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

I have been struggling with this problem for the last 3 days. I was able to install and run Apache on a CentOS machine. I can also run simple html or wsgi files. The problem is when I try to run Django. The Django project works fine with manage.py runserver, but when configuring the wsgi.py file and the .config file I start having problems (500 error).

I have already tried [this approach](https://www.slideshare.net/GrahamDumpleton/getting-started-with-modwsgi) and I have also researched similar questions on stack overflow but I wasn't able to find the solution to my problem.

I included more details below. I hope you can help me, thanks!

error_log;

```
[Mon Apr 20 09:59:59.532476 2020] [:error] [pid 31466] [client 10.5.230.111:59479]   File "/srv/www/example/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 14, in <module>
[Mon Apr 20 09:59:59.532591 2020] [:error] [pid 31466] [client 10.5.230.111:59479]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Apr 20 09:59:59.532627 2020] [:error] [pid 31466] [client 10.5.230.111:59479] ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

example.config;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess python-home=/var/www/django/env/ python-path=/srv/www/example/mysite:/var/www/django/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages

    WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptAlias /exam /srv/www/example/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /srv/www/example/mysite/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    # Django static files, here you must specify your own path's
    Alias /static/ /srv/www/example/mysite/static/
    <Directory "/srv/www/example/mysite/static">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi;

```
import os
import sys
import site

for root, _, files in os.walk('/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django'):
    for f in files:
        os.system('dos2unix %s' % abspath(join(root, f)))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

site.addsitedir("/var/www/django/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages")

sys.path.append("/srv/www/example/mysite")
sys.path.append("/srv/www/example/mysite/mysite")

activate_this = "/var/www/django/env/bin/activate_this.py"

with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), activate_this, "exec")
    exec(code, dict(__file__=activate_this))

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Are you really using `/srv/www/example/mysite/mysite`? If not, made-up variable names make it more difficult to help. What is the `os.walk` code for? Note the mismatch between Python 3.4 there and Python 3.6 everywhere else.

Comment: Make sure you've installed Django in the virtual environment `/var/www/django/env/`. I don't think you need any of the code from `site.addsitedir(...) to `exec(...)` - the `python-home` and `python-path` parts of your Apache config should cover that. And you should just have `python-path=/srv/www/example/mysite` - remove `:/var/www/django/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

Comment: @Alasdair thank you for responding, just remove the  :/var/www/django/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages from the conf file, and remove the site.adddir from wsgi, and error is the same... one thing that makes sense, is the missmatch between Python versions, on the error_log I have this when starting;  Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations, perhaps a wrong path for python? but how do I fix that? Thank you!

Comment: @Alasdair Also, just updated the the path and change 3.4, to 3.6, also made sure python is installed on /var/www/django/env/

Comment: Your mod_wsgi package is for Python 2.7.5. You need to install a version compiled for Python 3.6. I'm not familiar with Centos so can't help with that. One option might be to use the [mod-wsgi Python package](https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/) which you can install into your virtual env using pip.